# How can I verify a secp256r1 signature using solidity

Tags: solidity, cryptography, signature, protocol, ecdsa

Sorry if you find these questions are basic, but I am new to encryption. As far as I know, Solidity have `ecrecover`  function for this purpose, but it use `secp256k1` signature. which I am intend to use `secp256r1`. I used the following steps in this [gist](https://gist.github.com/axic/5b33912c6f61ae6fd96d6c4a47afde6d) to get `r,s, an v values.`

Then I applied all secp256r1 verification from [WIKIpedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_Curve_Digital_Signature_Algorithm) as follow

```
 1. getting r,s, and v values. 
 2. verify that r, s are integers in [1,n-1].
 3. calculate the hashing of the message.
 4. calculate w = s^-1 mod n
 5. calculate the curve point (x1,y1) = u1 x G + u2 x Q
```

Hint: ecadd is adding point function I wrote. ecmul is a multiplication function, isPoint: check if the point is in the curve or not.

**My questions are,**

1- do I wrote the five steps of the equation correctly; I am not of the 4th and 5th steps. You can check the code of the verification function for further details.

2- if I want to check the verification. I should send a message and a signature. do I need to return more than True/False for verification.

```
// testing signature function
// getting r, s, and v values from signature.
// steps would be as follows
// 1. getting r,s, and v values.
function ectest(bytes32 hash, bytes sig) returns (bool) {
    bytes32 r;
    bytes32 s;
    uint8 v;

    if (sig.length != 65)
      return (false, 0);

    // The signature format is a compact form of:
    //   {bytes32 r}{bytes32 s}{uint8 v}
    // Compact means, uint8 is not padded to 32 bytes.
assembly {
    r := mload(add(sig, 32))
    s := mload(add(sig, 64))

    // Here we are loading the last 32 bytes. We exploit the fact that
    // 'mload' will pad with zeroes if we overread.
    // There is no 'mload8' to do this, but that would be nicer.
    v := byte(0, mload(add(sig, 96)))

    // Alternative solution:
    // 'byte' is not working due to the Solidity parser, so lets
    // use the second best option, 'and'
    // v := and(mload(add(sig, 65)), 255)
}

// albeit non-transactional signatures are not specified by the YP, one would expect it
// to match the YP range of [27, 28]

if (v < 27)
  v += 27;

if (v != 27 && v != 28)
    return (false, 0);

// 2. verify that r, s are integers in [1,n-1] using isPoint function
if(isPoint(r,s) == false)
{
  return (false, 0);
}


//3. calculate the hashing of the message
e = sha3(msg);

//4. let v be the leftmost bits of msg
// calculate above in the assembly code
// v



      //5. calculate w = s^-1 mod n
      w  = invmod(s,n);
      // u1 = v * w mod n
      u1 = (v * w) % n ;
      // u2 = r * w mod n
      u2 = (r * w) % n;

      //6. calculate the curve point (x1,y1) = u1 x G + u2 x Q
      (x3,y3)=  ecmul(gx,gy,u1);
      (x4,y4)= ecmul(gx,gy,u2);

      (x1,y1) = ecadd(x3,y3,x4,y4);
      //7. check the validation
      if (r == x1)
      {
        return (true);
      }
    }// end function
```

}

Comment: I'm disappointed that no one addresses his question. People assumed that he was asking about secp256k1.

Comment: Ah. Sorry, after reading the previous comment, I see he wants the secp256r1 curve.

Answer (score 3):

This is an imporant question, since all of the other world (mobile, smartcards, HSM's etc) uses secp256r1.

There's an article at
http://blog.enuma.io/update/2016/11/01/a-tale-of-two-curves-hardware-signing-for-ethereum.html

but unfortunately the codes actually implementing the functionality have disappeared. Planning to reverse engineer this from the bytecode, but it might take some time...

Comment: the link seems not working, Im seeking for a solidity implementation of signing function. any idea?

Answer (score 3):

There's a pure solidity implementation of SECP256R1 / P256 / PRIME256V1 at https://github.com/tdrerup/elliptic-curve-solidity.

Main drawback is probably that verifying a non-native signature in Solidity is fairly expensive. The repo includes some truffle tests that should be helpful to understand the formatting of the variables.

Answer (score -1):

Be carefull when you use the sign-function of web3js because it does some strange prefixing before signing.

I made a tutorial on how to [sign and verify data with solidity and web3js](https://github.com/pubkey/eth-crypto/blob/master/tutorials/signed-data.md).

Answer (score -2):

**1)** The `ecrecover` function is built into solidity, so you don't need all those steps.

**2)** It really depends on what you are doing with it. Keep in mind if you are signing a message (i.e. eth_personalSign) there is a message prefix prepended to the signed message, the string "\x19Ethereum Signed Message:\n" followed by the length of the message.

Using `ecrecover` is a bit complicated at first, but once you master it, an amazing world of possibilities is at your fingertips.

---

**Example Solidity Contract:**

```
contract Foobar {
    function checkSignature(bytes32 digest, uint8 v, bytes32 r, byres32 s) constant returns (address signer) {
        return ecrecover(digest, v, r, s);
    }
}
```

---

**Example JavaScript:**

```
var ethers = require('ethers');

var privateKey = "0x0123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123";
var signingKey = new ethers.SigningKey(privateKey);
// SigningKey {
//    privateKey: '0x0123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123',
//    publicKey: '0x026655feed4d214c261e0a6b554395596f1f1476a77d999560e5a8df9b8a1a3515',
//    address: '0x14791697260E4c9A71f18484C9f997B308e59325',
// }

// The id function computes the keccak256 of a utf-8 string
var digest = ethers.utils.id("Hello World);
// '0x592fa743889fc7f92ac2a37bb1f5ba1daf2a5c84741ca0e0061d243a2e6707ba'

var sig = signingKey.signMessage(digest);
// { 
//    recoveryParam: 0,
//    r: '0x79f56f3422dc67f57b2aeeb0b20295a99ec90420b203177f83d419c98beda7fe',
//    s: '0x1a9d05433883bdc7e6d882740f4ea7921ef458a61b2cfe6197c2bb1bc47236fd'
// }

var contract = new ethers.Contract( ... )

// The v needs 27 added to it; this is legacy from a Bitcoin standard
var req = contract.checkSig(digest, sig.recoveryParam + 27, sig.r, sig.s);

// Call the Solidity function
req.then(function(signer) {
    console.log(signer);
    // "0x14791697260E4c9A71f18484C9f997B308e59325"
});
```

---

**Real World Example:**

Here is a quick Sticker Registry I created for the Firefly sticker promotional campaign. Each sticker is procedurally generated and unique, and had a private key on the back, which could be used to redeem the sticker. But the private key has no funds. Instead a user uses their own funds to pay the gas to submit a message signed by the sticker's private key. The contract verifies the sticker is valid using `ecrecover` and looking up the sticker in a merkle tree and the sticker is then transferred to the user.

https://etherscan.io/address/0xb90e64082d00437e65a76d4c8187596bc213480a#code

Comment: `ecrecover` expects `Ed25519` signatures I believe